# Replicate my local database (Mysql) to remote database( phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql

My MySQL database (local server) is connected to a weather station. The data are updated continuously on my local server. My idea is to develop a web application that allows me to access this data.
My local database (MySQL) has to be replicated on a remote server (phpmyadmin)
The architecture is as follows:
[image: Arquitecture]

My questions are:
1- How I do the connection ? I know that I can import my cvs file manually but I don't want to do this.
2- Can I update the datas automatically in my remote server ?

NOTE: I only want to queries on my remote server (phpmyadmin), I will not create  or modify new datas.
Thanks you for your help.

Comment: What kind of synchronization do you mean?  Time?  Data?

Comment: Is your "phpMyAdmin server" in a shared data center environment? Or do you control it yourself?

Comment: @wallyk for example I want to export data every 10 minutes from my local server to my remote server.

Comment: @OllieJones phpmyadmin server is my hosting . thanks

Comment: @plhyhc yes, I want to replicate mysql database in my hosting with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As i understood, you want to make a copy of your local mysql data  on a remote server.

first of all **phpmyadmin** is a tool or webapp to access mysql , it is not a server itself.

and second

there are two type of replication approach

- Master-slave (read from slave , write to master, that will sync to slave)
  [How to do it](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql)
- <strike>Master- Master (whatever operation are on master that will also replicate on other master) [How to do it](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication)</strike> (Master-Master replication is deprecated. See [Group Replication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04) as a replacement)

You can choose the approach  as per your requirement

[Master-master vs master-slave database architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736969/master-master-vs-master-slave-database-architecture)

How to achieve replication

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: After reading your link has emerged a new problema.I cant  to configure my slave server because I have no access to the mysql shell from my control panel . Thank your for your help.

Comment: @developerCK while the master-slave replication between 2 servers, can some user connect and read data from the database in the slave server? Thanks

Comment: yes @Enrique, Slave is just a read replica of master. so , all read queries should hit th slave