# When to prefer master-slave and when to cluster?

Tags: database, database-replication, database-cluster

I know there have been many articles written about database replication. Trust me, I spent some time reading those articles including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736969/master-master-vs-master-slave-database-architecture) SO one that explaints the pros and cons of replication. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189903/scaling-solutions-for-mysql-replication-clustering) SO article goes in depth about replication and clustering individually, but doesn't answer these simple questions that I have:

1. *When* do you replicate your database, and when do you cluster?
2. Can both be performed at the same time? If yes, what are the inspirations for each?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

MySQL currently supports two different solutions for creating a high availability environment and achieving multi-server scalability.

**MySQL Replication**

The first form is replication, which MySQL has supported since MySQL version 3.23. Replication in MySQL is currently implemented as an asyncronous master-slave setup that uses a logical log-shipping backend.

A master-slave setup means that one server is designated to act as the master. It is then required to receive all of the write queries. The master then executes and logs the queries, which is then shipped to the slave to execute and hence to keep the same data across all of the replication members.

Replication is asyncronous, which means that the slave server is not guaranteed to have the data when the master performs the change. Normally, replication will be as real-time as possible. However, there is no guarantee about the time required for the change to propagate to the slave.

Replication can be used for many reasons. Some of the more common reasons include scalibility, server failover, and for backup solutions.

Scalibility can be achieved due to the fact that you can now do can do SELECT queries across any of the slaves. Write statements however are not improved generally due to the fact that writes have to occur on each of the replication member.

Failover can be implemented fairly easily using an external monitoring utility that uses a heartbeat or similar mechanism to detect the failure of a master server. MySQL does not currently do automatic failover as the logic is generally very application dependent. Keep in mind that due to the fact that replication is asynchronous that it is possible that not all of the changes done on the master will have propagated to the slave.

MySQL replication works very well even across slower connections, and with connections that aren't continuous. It also is able to be used across different hardware and software platforms. It is possible to use replication with most storage engines including MyISAM and InnoDB.

**MySQL Cluster**

MySQL Cluster is a shared nothing, distributed, partitioning system that uses synchronous replication in order to maintain high availability and performance.

MySQL Cluster is implemented through a separate storage engine called NDB Cluster. This storage engine will automatically partition data across a number of data nodes. The automatic partitioning of data allows for parallelization of queries that are executed. Both reads and writes can be scaled in this fashion since the writes can be distributed across many nodes.

Internally, MySQL Cluster also uses synchronous replication in order to remove any single point of failure from the system. Since two or more nodes are always guaranteed to have the data fragment, at least one node can fail without any impact on running transactions. Failure detection is automatically handled with the dead node being removed transparent to the application. Upon node restart, it will automatically be re-integrated into the cluster and begin handling requests as soon as possible.

There are a number of limitations that currently exist and have to be kept in mind while deciding if MySQL Cluster is the correct solution for your situation.

Currently all of the data and indexes stored in MySQL Cluster are stored in main memory across the cluster. This does restrict the size of the database based on the systems used in the cluster.

MySQL Cluster is designed to be used on an internal network as latency is very important for response time.

As a result, it is not possible to run a single cluster across a wide geographic distance. In addition, while MySQL Cluster will work over commodity network setups, in order to attain the highest performance possible special clustering interconnects can be used.

Comment: my question was more regarding the reasoning involved in the choice.

Comment: can you write also something about Galera? Can you compare the maintenance effort Master/Slave vs Galera?

Answer (score 4):

1. In Master-Salve configuration the write operations are performed by Master and Read by slave. So all SQL request first reaches the Master and a queue of request is maintained and the read operation get executed only after completion of write. There is a common problem in Master-Salve configuration which i also witnessed is that when queue becomes too large to be maintatined by master then this achitecture collapse and the slave starts behaving like master.
   For clusters i have worked on Cassandra where the request reaches a node(table) and a commit hash is maintained which notices the differences made to a node and updates the other nodes based on that commit hash. So here all operations are not dependent on a single node.

We used Master-Salve when write data is not big in size and count otherwise we use clusters.
Clusters are expensive in space and Master-Salve in time so your desicion of what to choose depends on what you want to save.

2. We can also use both at the same time, i have done this in my current company.
   We moved the tables with most write operations to Cassandra and we have written 4 API to perform the CRUD operation on tables in Cassandra. As whenever an HTTP request comes it first hits our web server and from the code running on our web server we can decide which operation has to be performed (among CRUD) and then we call that particular API to make changes to the cassandra database.